# Galaxy note 3 and Galaxy note 12.2 out of memory error

Tags: android, android-studio, out-of-memory

Hi a have a app thats using support tablayout and cardView in a recyclerView, the app runs smooth on devices like Xperia m2 4.4 galaxy tab 2 and 3 jelly beam and a couple of jellybean htc devices... But when i run the app on galaxy note device i can't swip to next tab witout getting out of memory errors and even just opening the navigationView that has a header throws out of memory errors "Failed to allocate a 511500 byte allocation with 229064 free bytes and 223KB until OOM" thats just from navigationView I dont understand why these devices that has more ram and better cpu do this...  Both devices run lollipop. Is there someone else who faceed this problem.. Please im using Android studio and im java... Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Which drawable folder do you use for images? It is very important.

Comment: all images are in one drawable folder, they are all the same size 480x269 and i use asyncetask to decode bitmap files.. the error comes from asynctask doInBackground method thats where i load the bitmaps

Comment: I wrote an answer, not a comment because it was long. You should check it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong then(According to your comment / If All images in one drawable folder). You must seperate all screen sizes to different drawable folders which you are supporting. Also you need to resize them before putting into folders. Otherwise you will get OOM error

For example:

```
 res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for medium-density
 res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/graphic.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
 res/drawable-xxhdpi/graphic.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

Comment: I understand what your saying.. if i did that i'd have larger images for xxhdpi devices like galaxy note 12.2 with a 12 inch screen, which would use more momory. the app runs smooth on smaller screen devices that has less memory and less cpu,